# Make column levels into new columns R

Tags: r, transpose, levels

I have a `data table[1000+, 4]`.

One of the columns has `5 levels` and I want to make these 5 levels into 5 new columns.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

We extract the `levels` from the column of interest ('ColN'), convert to `list` and assign that to five 'new' columns.

```
df1[paste0("new", 1:5)] <- as.list(levels(df1$ColN))
head(df1,2)
#    ColN Col2 Col3 new1 new2 new3 new4 new5
#1    C    7    a    A    B    C    D    E
#2    A    4    b    A    B    C    D    E
levels(df1$ColN)
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```

data

```
set.seed(48)
df1 <- data.frame(ColN= sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, 
   replace=TRUE), Col2= sample(10), Col3= letters[1:10])
```

Comment: It doesn't give an error, but it doesn't change anything at all

Comment: @R.D.  It does changes based on the example I updated.